# Which paypal API I can use to accept money from mastercard/visa and transfer money from paypal to paypal or moneybookers

Tags: php, e-commerce, paypal

In my website, I want peoples to be able to pay us using their Mastercard/VISA/Paypal account. The payment amount must be added to my paypal merchant account.

Also, I want to transfer my paypal money to any other paypal/moneybookers account directly from my website. Which API/System is secure and suitable for my process?

Answer (score 0):

For accepting payments, you can use Website Payments Pro, Website Payments Standard or Express Checkout.  All three of these would allow you to accept payments.  As for sending money/transferring it to another PayPal account, you can use either the MassPayment API or the Adaptive Payments (Pay) API.